# SMOTE for image dataset

Tags: smote

I'm working on Image augmentation with Smote. I'm confused that how can SMOTE be useful for an image dataset with containing 5955 images with four classes(2552,227,621,2555).
Could anyone please help me? It would be greatly appreciated!
I appreciate your help in advance